# node-irc with Twitch.TV duplicate message issue

Tags: node.js, bots, twitch

My node-irc bot is sometimes repeating what it says in the chat. Sometimes it works perfectly; other times it repeats. I've looked all through my code and I cant find any recursion going on.

**Connection function (with my listeners)**

```
//connects the bot to the channel
this.connectToChannel = function(callback) {
    console.log("Connection");
    botInstance.connect();
    botInstance.join(currentChannel, function(){
        botInstance.say(currentChannel, initalConnectionMessage);
        console.log("Joined");
        callback();
    });
    botInstance.addListener("message", function(nick, to, text, message) {
        if (text == lastText){
            return; // you can i've tried to avoid this issue
        }

        bannedWords.forEach(function(item,index){
            if (text.includes(item)){
                parent.sendMessage(nick + " > You're not allowed to use that type of language.");
                parent.sendMessage("/timeout " + nick + " 10");
            }
        });

        commands.forEach(function(item, index){
            var splitData = text.split(' ');

            if (splitData[0] == item.getExecutor()) {
                //running this command

                var response = item.getResponse();
                response = response.replace("%user%", nick);
                response = response.replace("%bot_username%", config.botName);

                parent.sendMessage(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Bot Creation(This is being called before the connection)**

```
this.createBot = function(channel) {
    currentChannel = channel;

    var irc = require('irc');
    botInstance = new irc.Client(config.server, config.botName, {
        channels: [currentChannel + " " + config.oAuth],
        userName: config.botName,
        password: config.oAuth
    });
}
```

**Bot Sending Messages**

```
this.sendMessage = function(msg){
if(botInstance != null) {
    botInstance.say(currentChannel, msg);
    lastMessage = msg;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why aren't you using tmi.js for twitch chat bots?

Comment: @MattC Well node-irc is the first one I came across. Normally generic IRC clients work pretty good. Also if needed I can make this bot work other places. I'll look into tmi.js if my duplicate message issue continues.